# NamedClient is not giving response as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm using `Named Client` and created client as -

```
services.AddHttpClient("Clientname", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Tokenvalue);
});
```

In controllers:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getApps()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps");
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("Clientname");
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    return Ok(response);
}
```

The above implementation is giving the following response

```
{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Length","value":["86"]},{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/json; charset=utf-8"]}]},"statusCode":404,"reasonPhrase":"Not Found","headers":[{"key":"Date","value":["Wed, 17 Jul 2019 17:49:13 GMT"]},{"key":"Server","value":["nginx"]},{"key":"X-Cascade","value":["pass"]},{"key":"X-Content-Type-Options","value":["nosniff"]},{"key":"X-Vcap-Request-Id","value":["ad5f538c-X-X-X-X::X-X-X-X-ef56283150cf"]}],"requestMessage":{"version":{"major":2,"minor":0,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":null,"method":{"method":"GET"},"requestUri":"https://api.example.io/apps","headers":[{"key":"Authorization","value":["Bearer Tokenvalue"]}],"properties":{}},"isSuccessStatusCode":false}
```

But when I implement it without the named client it works, implantation without the named client using `Flurl`-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getApps()
{
    var ul = Path.Combine(baseurl, "apps");

    return Ok(await ul.WithOAuthBearerToken(TokenValue).GetJsonAsync());
}
```

The expected response from the external API is a list of apps in JSON format.

I'm, not sure what I'm doing, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your serialize the `HttpResponseMessage` instead of getting the *actual* JSON response body out of it. The third-party library you're using in the second scenario, likely does this via the `GetJsonAsync()` call, which is why it works in that case.

In any case, you need to do something like:

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

That of course is going to give you the body as a string. If you want to actually deserialize the JSON string into an object you can either run the value through `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` or use `ReadAsAsync<T>` instead.